# how to use bootstrap 5.3 popover properly?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create web with bunch of popover, let's say:

```
<a tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="popover">popover 1</a>
<a tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="popover">popover 2</a>
```

And the content is:

```
<div id="content1" class="bs-none">
   <p>very long content for popover1</p>
</div>

<div id="content2" class="bs-none">
   <p>very long content for popover2</p>
</div>
```

The question is, how to create those popover show it's own content with minimum script?

the target want to achieve is to activate popover same or different content with minimum script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the id of the content div as a data attribute of the trigger a element:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]');

  const popovers = [...elems].map(el => new bootstrap.Popover(el, {
trigger: 'focus',
html: true,
content: document.getElementById(el.dataset.contentId)?.innerHTML || ''
  }));
});
```

```css
    body, html {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .popover-container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100%;
      gap: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-aFq/bzH65dt+w6FI2ooMVUpc+21e0SRygnTpmBvdBgSdnuTN7QbdgL+OapgHtvPp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-heAjqF+bCxXpCWLa6Zhcp4fu20XoNIA98ecBC1YkdXhszjoejr5y9Q77hIrv8R9i" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="popover-container">
  <a tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-content-id="content1">popover 1</a>
  <a tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-content-id="content2">popover 2</a>
</div>
<div id="content1" class="bs-none">
  <p>very long content for popover1</p>
</div>
<div id="content2" class="bs-none">
  <p>very long content for popover2</p>
</div>
```